# laravel pagination coloring my crud list items on the basis of expiry_date

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

> I was coloring my crud list items on the basis of expiry_date using this code [this is my code which is working fine before enabling ajax](https://pastebin.com/9DYgazAm)

Now I recently applied laravel pagination to my crud using enable ajaxtable and after enabling it it was showing error at

```
<?php
  use Carbon\Carbon;
  $today_date = Carbon::now();
  $expiry_date = []; // array();

   // this is where laravel showing error  // 
      foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) {
      $expiry_date[] = Carbon::parse($entry->expiry_date);
   }
   $expiry_date = []; // array();
?>
```

and this is my code what i have done to solve the problem [here](https://pastebin.com/TYepyfee) but not worked

Comment: What error is laravel showing you?  Where does $entries variable come from?

Comment: here is my upgraded question sir plz check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048791/how-to-change-the-color-of-each-crud-entry-when-ajax-table-is-enabled